# Maximal subgroups of indefinite special orthogonal group SO(p,q)

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Can someone answer the following question:
 Is there any classification of maximal proper Zariski-closed real subgroups of $SO(p,q)$ which are not parabolic, and satisfy the following conditions:

1. they have rank at least the rank of $SO(p) \times SO(q)$ .
2. they should act irreducibly on the natural representation of $SO(p,q)$, i.e. on $\mathbb{R}^{p,q}$.

Thanks.

Comment: The references given in [this answer](http://mathoverflow.net/a/111532/19276) classify all maximal subgroups; perhaps extracting the ones you want is not too hard?

Comment: Forgive me asking this: I tried to get the papers you suggested from my library, but I could not get them. Do you have access to them, and in case if they are allowed to be shared, would you please share them with me?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have copies at hand; have you tried interlibrary loan?

Comment: @Francois: The paper by Taufik contains classification of irreducible maximal subalgebras. In that paper, he mentions that the reducible ones are given in http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=uzku&paperid=408&option_lang=eng

Comment: I'm afraid Mušic's paper hasn't been translated. OTOH, you should be able to find translations of Dynkin's, in "Selected papers of E. B. Dynkin with commentary".

Answer (score 1):

A Russian mathematician whose name is Komrakov, has listed the maximal subgroups of SO(p,q), if you do not find the articles, i have the pdf fil's, best regards jorge

Comment: Note that the key paper by Komrakov is one of the references mentioned by Francois, though it lacks full details.    The basic source is the older classification work by Dynkin.

Comment: Thanks to Francois, I found the references. The paper by Komrakov contains final results at the Lie algebra level. If you have the papers that have proofs, please send it to me.