# Maximal subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

I would like to find a list (or at least a description) of the maximal closed connected subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{R})$ , and also of $\mathrm{SU}(p,q)$.

In the following [MO discussion](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60315/modern-reference-for-maximal-connected-subgroups-of-compact-lie-groups) is indicated a link to a nice paper of Dynkin where he classifies the closed Lie subgroups of $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{C})$, but I'm not sure if one can deduce the answer to my question from this classification.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For $su(p,q)$, I found

Selim, Taufik Mohamed
On maximal subalgebras in classical real Lie algebras.
Selected translations. Selecta Math. Soviet. 6 (1987), no. 2, 163–176.

See also this [MO problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102560/reference-request-for-the-list-of-maximal-subgroups-of-su3-1?rq=1%20%22MO%20problem%22.).

Comment: I can't find the paper anywhere, any clue?

Comment: Are you still in Paris? There, three libraries are carrying the journal (ENS, Jussieu, Orsay). See http://cfp.mathdoc.fr/periodique.php?id=4604.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know about this catalogue, very useful indeed!

Answer (score 2):

Maximal closed connected subgroups of positive dimension in $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ are parabolic, the normalizer of a connected semisimple subgroup, or the normalizer of a maximal torus.   There are finitely many conjugation classes of each type, and so you could try to work out the maximal ones.

**General References**

According to the MathSciNet review (see also MO answers [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/111532/12218) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/181867/12218)) this paper addresses the problem (without proof):

Komrakov, B. P. *Maximal subalgebras of real Lie algebras and a problem of Sophus Lie.* Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR 311 (1990), no. 3, 528--532; translation in Soviet Math. Dokl. 41 (1990), no. 2, 269–273 (1991)

Another paper that might be helpful is:

Mostow, G. D. *On maximal subgroups of real Lie groups.* 
Ann. of Math. (2) 74 1961 503–517.

Comment: I am not sure why these papers would contain a solution since a maximal subalgebra doesn't have to be simple and a simple subalgebra doesn't have to be maximal. These problems are related but not the same.

Comment: @FriedrichKnop Yes, I had in mind using the Karpelevič papers with Dynkin's classification.  I edited the answer accordingly and added some other references that claim to directly deal with maximal subgroups/subalgebras.  Thanks for the comment.